# schema.sql executed before table creation, inserts in schema.sql fails

Tags: mysql, spring, jdbc, spring-boot, h2

I have a project with Table entity. I want to run some SQL from `schema.sql` to update my table for test. but I find out that Spring first apply `schema.sql` then create tables with `@Table` annotation. 
so the table is not created and I get the error message that says:

nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "BOOK" not found; SQL statement:

this is my Table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="BOOK")
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long bookId;
//and all getter and setters
```

and this is `scheam.sql`

```
INSERT INTO book VALUES (1, 'Of Mice and Men', '1954-11-08', 100, 11.00);
INSERT INTO book VALUES (2, 'One Flew Over the Cuckoos Nest', '1973-11-08', 100, 15.00);
INSERT INTO book VALUES (3, 'For Whom the Bell Tolls', '1932-11-08', 100, 13.00);
```

so I want to first create Tables and then apply my `schema.sql`. how I can get that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**schema.sql** is for creating tables (`CREATE TABLE`, ...), not for inserting records. I don't know how you create your tables, but I guess they either are already created or you are using something like Hibernate's generate DDL option.

Anyhow, to insert or update records in an existing table, you should use **data.sql**. So in your case you should rename the file to data.sql to make it work.

More information about this can be found in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html).

Comment: yes that right. they are creates by using @Table anotation. ok let me check and renaming.

Answer (score 0):

1.) rename the file to data.sql

2.) Add the below row to the application.properties:

spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization = true